# Django: prefetch related: for loop: based on how we call for loop, the number of sql call varies

Tags: sql, django, prefetch

In django i am trying to understand prefetch:

I have two for loop scenarios after prefetch

```
symbollist = SymbolList.objects.prefetch_related('some_related_name')[0:10]
for i in range(0,10):
    print(symbollist[i].some_related_name)
```

Now it calls sql N+1 times

where as

```
symbollist = SymbolList.objects.prefetch_related('some_related_name')[0:10]
for symbol in symbollist:
    print(symbol.some_related_name)
```

this will call only two sqls

Why so

Comment: They both executed N+1 queries for me?  Please provide a *minimal, reproducible, example*

Answer (score 1):

You are limiting `symbol_list` Queryset to 10 objects and caching related data for them using prefetch_related

but you are iterating through all the objects in database (notice count)

```
for i in range(0,symbollist.count()):
```

Comment: even if i try to do `print(symbollist[0].some_related_name` it runs query

Comment: Show us minimal reproducible example by including models into question also why the second print in question is not like    print(symbol.some_related_name)